# Add new XElement with data type attribute

Tags: c#, linq, xelement

Hi I have an xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TreeList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Columns>
    <Column>
      <ColumnName>123</ColumnName>
      <ColumnType>Bound</ColumnType>
    </Column>
  </Columns>
  <Nodes>
    <Node Id="0" ParentId="-1">
      <NodeData>
        <Cell xsi:type="xsd:string">Node1</Cell>
      </NodeData>
    </Node>
    <Node Id="1" ParentId="0">
      <NodeData>
        <Cell xsi:type="xsd:string">Node11</Cell>
      </NodeData>
    </Node>
  </Nodes>
</TreeList>
```

and I need to add new XElement:

```
<Node Id="xx" ParentId="yy">
  <NodeData>
    <Cell xsi:type="xsd:string">NewNode</Cell>
  </NodeData>
</Node>
```

my problem is at "xsi:type="xsd:string" part of the XElement. How can I set XAttribute like this?

I tried following:

```
    public static void AdNewNode(string filePath, string id, string parentId, string value)
    {
        XElement xml = XElement.Load(filePath);
        XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        XNamespace xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
        XAttribute attribute1 = new XAttribute(xsd + "string", string.Empty);
        XAttribute attribute2 = new XAttribute(xsi + "type", attribute1.ToString());

        XElement innerNode = new XElement("NodeData", 
                        new XElement("Cell",attribute2, attribute1, value));
        XElement elemnet = new XElement("Node", new XAttribute("Id", id), new XAttribute("ParentId", parentId), innerNode);

        xml.Add(elemnet);
   }
```

And this is result:

```
<Node Id="2" ParentId="1">
  <NodeData>
    <Cell p3:type="p0:string=&quot;&quot;" p4:string="" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:p3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">New Node</Cell>
  </NodeData>
</Node>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

`"xsd:string"` is just plain string, so you should be able to construct `xsi:type` attribute like so :

```
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
XAttribute attribute = new XAttribute(xsi+"type", "xsd:string");
```

Then add the `attribute` to it's parent element casually :

```
XElement innerNode = new XElement("NodeData",
                        new XElement("Cell", attribute, value));
XElement elemnet = new XElement("Node", 
                        new XAttribute("Id", id), 
                        new XAttribute("ParentId", parentId), 
                        innerNode);
```